# how to replace Nivo slider "prev" & "next" with images(arrows)

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

I am using Nivo slider...

I have managed to hide the numbers from the bottom of the slider using css.

what I want to do now is replace the "prev" & "next" with arrows that I have made in photoshop...
I have been searching on here and on google but I am not able to find a solution.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help please.

Sandeep

Comment: The options are explicitly named prevText and nextText, and from their naming I’d assume that’s all they do, insert _plain text_. Probably the easiest solution would be to leave these in place, and have the text hidden and replaced by a background image using one of the image replacement techniques out there …

Answer (score 5):

I'd use CSS image replacement for this. So:

```
.nivo-directionNav .nivo-prevNav {
  background:transparent url(path/to/image) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height:20px; /*height of img*/
  width:10px; /*width of img*/
  text-indent:-10000px; /*moving the default text*/
  overflow:hidden; /*hiding the default text*/
}
```

Then repeat for .nivo-nextNav. You can also use positioning to put the arrows where you want them in the slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a new theme with your own images and settings, see here: http://support.dev7studios.com/articles/nivo-slider-jquery-plugin/creating-custom-themes

OR by changing the png image for the buttons, into an existing theme.

Comment: Readers should note this is only valid for the WordPress plugin version of the Nivo Slider.

Comment: How comes that? It's valid for both versions.

Comment: You're correct, my mistake. Got this link confused with another I guess.

Answer (score 0):

include this line in your file

`<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

and include `background:url(arrows.png) no-repeat;` in .theme-default .nivo-directionNav a in the default.css file stored in the default folder. note that the arrow image must be stored in the same folder as where the defalut.css is placed. hope this will help.